# How to write a bash script when a login is involved

Tags: bash, ansible, gluu

I am trying to script the installation of Gluu Server with Ansible.
I have the following script at the end which is supposed to launch the final setup. The issue is that the script stops after the login and restarts if I exit:

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/gluu-server-2.4.2 login
cd /install/community-edition-setup/
./setup.py -n -u  -a   -s -f setup.properties
```

EDIT

In fact the login command issues a chroot command which is the source of my challenge:

```
/usr/sbin/chroot /opt/gluu-server-2.4.2/ su -
```

Comment: Could you link to the gluu source? The init.d source will have the clues.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that the `chroot` and `su` start up new processes, they don't affect the process that invokes them. The `chroot` creates a new process to run the `su` command in, and the `su` command ends up creating a new shell process. It's this new shell that has the changed root directory. When you exit that shell it resumes executing your script, which never had is root changed. The `./setup.py` command is then executed in the wrong context.

The solution is to execute the commands in the process that `su` creates.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/chroot /opt/gluu-server-2.4.2/ su -l -c "
    cd /install/community-edition-setup/;
    ./setup.py -n -u  -a   -s -f setup.properties"
```

This may not work if `./setup.py` needs to interact with the user or otherwise needs a controlling terminal. In that case you may need something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/chroot /opt/gluu-server-2.4.2/ /bin/bash -l -c "
    cd /install/community-edition-setup/;
    ./setup.py -n -u  -a   -s -f setup.properties"
```

In this case the script would already need to be running as root, but you normally need to be root invoke the `chroot` command anyways.

Comment: The n flag is for non interactive so this should work fine. I check and come back to hopefully accept the answer. Thanks